# Quickest way of encrypting Java code

Tags: java, encryption

I just jumped into a big trouble. I created a commercial application in Java and it is in test mode, and some one has de-compiled my code without my permission. I need to protect my code as soon as possible, as the next release is in next 2 days. What is the quickest and fastest way of encrypting my code in Java? Is there any program or something which will encrypt the entire code at once?

Comment: ProGuard -- http://proguard.sourceforge.net/

Comment: google for "obfuscator java" lot of them free in internet.

Comment: If you use reflection in your code, code obfuscation is not a good idea.

Comment: If you're actually sending out jar files, theres nothing you can do to stop a sufficiently determined person from reading your code to some extent, even after obfuscation.

Comment: @LouisWasserman: I don't know, but this person has violated my rights as well as my client's! what is the other solution you suggest pls?

Comment: Webapps don't have to be run on client side, which protects their server-side source, but aside from that you don't have any really secure options.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not really looking for *encryption*. After all, the code needs to be run by your clients, so if you encrypted then they'd need the decryption key, which would defeat the point.

What you want is *obfuscation*, which turns code into something that's semantically equivalent, but very hard for a human to understand. For that, ProGuard is probably the best in the business.

But make sure you thoroughly test your obfuscated version, just in case something has gone wrong. (And it might, depending on how clean your code is.)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. FYI, I am using Netbeans generated GUI code with manually written database classes.